# What is meant by intention to treat analysis?

Tags: self-study, survey, clinical-trials, random-allocation

What is meant by intention to treat analysis and how to use this method in a statistical software? (For example in SAS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intention to treat is the policy that all participants in a trial should be analyzed in the arm to which they were allocated not the treatment they actually received. This avoids a number of possible biases due to differential uptake of treatment. It has nothing to do with which statistical analysis you choose nor with which software you employ.